# Is there an OS that can boot .vhd

Tags: operating-systems, vhd

Is there an Operating system that can load .vhd files and run them like if it was a virtual machine? And if there is how can I use it? I have tried Grub4Dos but that probably isn't what its for

Comment: What would be the point, that's what virtual machine software is for.

Comment: Yes; Windows 10